# .NET RedirectStandardOutput not working for linux

Tags: .net, linux, process

This part of the code works fine for Windows(10), but doesn't work on linux.
While the rest of my program works correctly.

Purpose: to get the output of the running process. (he definitely is)

```
var p = new Process();

var psi = new ProcessStartInfo()
{
    FileName = filePath,
    RedirectStandardError = true,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    UseShellExecute = false,
};

p.StartInfo = psi;

p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
p.OutputDataReceived += (sender, a) => Console.WriteLine(a.Data);
p.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, a) => Console.WriteLine(a.Data);

p.Start();
p.BeginOutputReadLine();
p.BeginErrorReadLine();

p.WaitForExit();
```

**UPD:** I have made various attempts. With usging and without. Async methods and synchronous. I made checks in the OS, the process definitely starts, but the redirect output does not arrive.

I also tried different linux distributions: debian and ubuntu x64. (virtual box) The result is the same - empty.

**UPD 2 important:** The program whose output I'm trying to intercept, I downloaded from the official site "SA-MP": version 0.3.7-R2 Linux Server (x86).

If you run the code with "RedirectStandardOutput = false ", there is program output in the console, but if "RedirectStandardOutput = true" and an attempt to read StandardOutput - the code seems to freeze.

You can download the program I am trying to listen to and see for yourself.

Comment: How does it not work?

Comment: @klutt | Here and so. This does not work. I've just updated the description so you can find the program I'm trying to intercept and try it for yourself.